# How to display static google map on android imageview?

Tags: android

I want to display a static google map on an imageview. Something similar to "Whatsapp" showing while share the location. How can I do this?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Google offers the static map API for that you need an API key.

You can download a dynamically configured bitmap from the web, store it on the filesystem or on memory, then get drawable from it in order to set it to the ImageView.

You need to generate an url from your coordinates to load the data from the web using this url. Exemple for a 200x200 bitmap showing the eiffel Tower in Paris:

```
String latEiffelTower = "48.858235";
String lngEiffelTower = "2.294571";
String url = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latEiffelTower + "," + lngEiffelTower + "&zoom=15&size=200x200&sensor=false&key=YOUR_API_KEY"
```

StackOverflow already have some answer on how to download an image from the web in order to display it in an image view: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=imageview+url+%5Bandroid%5D)

You can find here the documentation for the [Google Static Maps API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/).

Comment: That's great! I used a second mapview which caused me a lot of trouble (normally you can only have one per process), but I'll probably stick to this solution. Just a question - does the 25k downloads per app (https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/#Limits) apply here? If so, how do they check it? Requests come from different devices, the url doesn't have an api key...

Comment: you are right, without an api key, they cannot enforce the 25K limit per app. For now this api probably doesn't have a limit, if requests comes from different ips.

Comment: How to add the marker on the map with this snippet?

Comment: Now, this is not the best solution because API has changed, now an API key is required, if not provided, it sometimes returns an error. Furthermore, there is a limit of 25k requests per day.

Answer (score 19):

```
public static Bitmap getGoogleMapThumbnail(double lati, double longi){
        String URL = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" +lati + "," + longi + "&zoom=15&size=200x200&sensor=false";
        Bitmap bmp = null;
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();   
        HttpGet request = new HttpGet(URL); 

        InputStream in = null;
        try {
            in = httpclient.execute(request).getEntity().getContent();
            bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            in.close();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bmp;
    }
```

Comment: You need API key to use this

Comment: The Google Maps Platform server rejected your request. You must use an API key to authenticate each request to Google Maps Platform APIs. For additional information, please refer to http://g.co/dev/maps-no-account

Comment: in kotlin I am getting Unresolved reference: HttpClient

Answer (score 18):

You can also display a static image natively with the SDK now (this was added in December 2014):
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/lite

That will result in a MapView.

Comment: This is the best answer nowadays.

Comment: Do you have a full example on how to use it?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend this, even in lite mode the MapView object will hang up your UI for a second when it loads, this is especially apparent if you were to load a map image in a RecyclerView. So depending on your use case, you may want to go with the static image API.

Answer (score 5):

**Web view is my suggestion for it.**

Create an html file *static_map.html* inside html folder in asset folder

its content may be like the below

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style>
    html,body{
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    .map{
        position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<img class="map" src="REPLACE_HERE" >
</body>
</html>
```

Then programmatically create a static map URL and replace **REPLACE_HERE** string with it. Then load it on the web view. This will reduce our effort very much.

The code is as follows

```
try {
    String url ="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?";
    url+="&zoom=13";
    url+="&size=600x300";
    url+="&maptype=roadmap";
    url+="&markers=color:green%7Clabel:G%7C"+latitude+", "+longitude;
    url+="&key="+ YOUR_GOOGLE_API_KEY;

    InputStream is = context.getAssets().open("html/static_map.html");
    int size = is.available();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
    is.read(buffer);
    is.close();
    String str = new String(buffer);
    str = str.replace("REPLACE_HERE", url);
    wv_map.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv_map.loadDataWithBaseURL("", str, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
} catch (IOException e) {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, another solution is the Picasso library: "*A powerful image downloading and caching library for Android*"

You give an image url to Picasso and then It does a GET petition and it loads the image. If the petition fails then Picasso can set a default image.

You can even set a progress animation while the image is loading.

It is a good and clean solution.

A example:

```
ImageView ivUrl = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv_photo);

Picasso.with(getContext()).cancelRequest(ivUrl);

Picasso.with(getContext())
    .load(imageUrlString)
    .error(R.drawable.ic_error)
    .placeholder(R.drawable.progress_animation)
    .into(ivUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?" +
          "center=40.714%2c%20-73.998" +
          "&zoom=12&size=400x400" +              
          "&key=YOUR_API_KEY_GOES_HERE;
Picasso.get()
            .load(url)
            .into(imageView, new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "Error to load Maps: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

As refered by @pcans, i really like his solution. You can use string as URL to load your image in ImageView. I suggest a third party library for image loading :
https://github.com/koush/ion

Hope that it can help you :)

Answer (score -5):

Firstly you take the image of your map which you show in drawable folder after that use as a background of that imageView.