# Get piece of GoogleMap

Tags: android, dictionary

Is there any possibility to capture piece of `GoogleMap` based on coords without displaying map and save it? I know there is `SnapshotReadyCallback` method, but I have to create map view to be able to do this. Any possibility to create something like

```
 GoogleMap gm = new GoogleMap()
```

and then call

```
 SnapshotReadyCallback
```

or should I create map in `xml` file and then hide it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Google Static maps API to get an image of a map without having to load it on you devices screen.

Here is the documentation for Google Static maps API : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/staticmaps/index

Use one of the answers on this question to get the image from that API as a bitmap: [How to display static google map on android imageview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324004/how-to-display-static-google-map-on-android-imageview)

I am not sure if this is what you are after and since I spent all my credits on a bounty I cant post comments asking for more info any-more :(