# Screenshot the google map programmatically?

Tags: android, google-maps, screenshot

I want to create an Image. Image should contain an image taken by **camera,** **current address** and a **`googlemap`** with current location.

[image]

I can able to take an screenshot of a particular area with location text and getting it as an image. 
Issue geting is **Map** area remains blank(black)

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18093295/5049244) but not clear to make it success

How to achieve this like in an Image. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way to get image (Bitmap) of Google map - use [Google Maps Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro). For downloading Bitmap with map for your lat/lng coordinates of map center and zoom you can use code like this:

```
...
private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
...

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    ...
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this); 

}

...
// Somewhere, when you need map image
if (checkPermission()) {

    mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(MainActivity.this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    if (location != null) {
                        String mapUrl = buildStaticApiUrl(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()), zoom, mapWidthInPixels, mapHeightInPixels);

                        try {
                            Bitmap mapBitmap = new GetStaticMapAsyncTask().execute(mapUrl).get();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (ExecutionException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Where `buildStaticApiUrl()` can be like:

```
private String buildStaticApiUrl(LatLng center, int zoom, int width, int height) {

    StringBuilder url = new StringBuilder();
    url.append("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?");
    url.append(String.format("center=%8.5f,%8.5f", center.latitude, center.longitude));
    url.append(String.format("&zoom=%d", zoom));
    url.append(String.format("&size=%dx%d", width, height));
    url.append(String.format("&key=%s", getResources().getString(R.string.google_maps_key)));

    return url.toString();
}
```

and `GetStaticMapAsyncTask` like:

```
private class GetStaticMapAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {

        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;

        try {
            URL url = new URL(params[0]);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            connection.connect();

            InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap mapBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream);

            // draw blue circle on current location
            Paint locaionMarkerPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
            locaionMarkerPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);

            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(mapBitmap.getWidth(), mapBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
            canvas.drawBitmap(mapBitmap,0,0, null);
            canvas.drawCircle(mapBitmap.getWidth()/ 2, mapBitmap.getHeight() / 2, 20, locaionMarkerPaint);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (connection != null) {
                connection.disconnect();
            }
        }

        return bitmap;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }
}
```

Then, when you got both `pictureFromCameraBitmap` and `mapBitmap` Bitmaps you can combine them into one `pictureBitmap` like that way:

```
public Bitmap composeBitmap(Bitmap pictureBitmap, Bitmap mapBitmap, LatLng location) {
    Bitmap wholeBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(pictureBitmap.getWidth(), pictureBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(wholeBitmap);
    canvas.drawBitmap(pictureBitmap,0,0, null);
    canvas.drawBitmap(mapBitmap,0,wholeBitmap.getHeight() - mapBitmap.getHeight(), null);

    String text = getCurrentTimeStr() + getAddress(location);
    canvas.drawText(text, 0, 0, null);

    return wholeBitmap;
}
```

and `getAddress()` can be like that

```
public String getAddress(LatLng location) {
    StringBuilder addr = new StringBuilder();
    Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());
    try {
        List<Address> addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.latitude, location.longitude, 1);
        Address obj = addresses.get(0);
        addr.append(obj.getAddressLine(0));
    } catch (IOException e) {
    }

    return addr.toString();
}
```

Or, if you don't want to use Static Maps API, you can use `MapView`-based workaround for map snapshot like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49139366/6950238) or [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48631146/6950238) answers:

```
GoogleMapOptions options = new GoogleMapOptions()
        .compassEnabled(false)
        .mapToolbarEnabled(false)
        .camera(CameraPosition.fromLatLngZoom(KYIV,15))
        .liteMode(true);
mMapView = new MapView(this, options);
...

mMapView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
mMapView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mMapWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
        View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mMapHeight, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
mMapView.layout(0, 0, mMapWidth, mMapHeight);
mMapView.buildDrawingCache(true);
Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(mMapView.getDrawingCache());  // <- that is bitmap with map image
mMapView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, will try and let you know

Comment: @ArnoldBrown Did you try to get screenshot?

Comment: Will this used to take a screenshot of a particular view which has MapView and textviews like in an Image in my question?. Finally need it as an image?

Comment: @ArnoldBrown The code above makes "screenshot" only of `MapView` (it saved to `Bitmap b`  variable). Than you can add anything what you need to that bitmap, or otherwise add that bitmap to other (e.g. camera image).

Comment: Actually i did the functionality for Taking Screen shot of particular View that contain text and a captured image, saving it as an image in a custom directory.

Comment: If i get a mapview alone which is a part of that view then how to add the map image to the other image to get as an image in my question?

Comment: ie. how to add that Bitmap b to other image in particular area?

Comment: @ArnoldBrown Takea look for example at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13361456/6950238) answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use View and find view and drawing cache and take a screen shot.

```
               View v = rootView.findViewById(R.id.frmMapView);                                     v.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                Bitmap backBitmap = v.getDrawingCache();
                Bitmap tripimage = Bitmap.createBitmap(
                        backBitmap.getWidth(), backBitmap.getHeight(),
                        backBitmap.getConfig());
                Canvas canvas = new Canvas(tripimage);
                canvas.drawBitmap(snapshot, new Matrix(), null);
                canvas.drawBitmap(backBitmap, 0, 0, null);

                bitmap = snapshot;

                profilePath = "/mnt/sdcard/" + "MyMapScreen" + System.currentTimeMillis() + ".png";
                FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(profilePath);
                tripimage.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
```

Comment: @ArnoldBrown if it is usefull or not let me know

Comment: What is snapshot in your coding?