# Draw MapView on Canvas Android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-layout, android-canvas, android-mapview

I try to add MapView to Canvas.
But when i do mapView.draw(canvas); there is no map that appear.

Trying manually using xml and it can appear no problem. But when i set content view with canvas class, mapview not appear even though already passing the object

```
PageFlipView mPageFlipView = new PageFlipView(context)
setContentView(mPageFlipView);
```

class PageFlipView

```
public class PageFlipView extends GLSurfaceView implements Renderer {
```

How to do that?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can do it in two steps:

1) get `MapView` snapshot like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48631146/6950238) answer;

2) draw on `Canvas` not `MapView` but snapshot `Bitmap`.

Comment: But its not draggable. How can we make draggable

Comment: @Kubera One possible way - make snapshot that bigger than screen size. Bub better use Google Maps in "normal" mode.

Comment: Can u share sample code?