# Android Google Maps no UI

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

Replicating some behavior in an iOS app to Android and one of the requirements is to be able to generate a map snapshot. Google maps does offers the ability to create a [snapshot](https://github.com/kaeawc/android-maps-example/blob/master/maps/src/com/example/mapdemo/SnapshotDemoActivity.java) of a map but unlike the iOS app I don't see a way of creating the map purely in memory and then saving it to a DB. I've created maps before but it was always done with the intent of showing the map and the user interacting with it. In this scenario I don't want any of that. There should be no map to be viewed at this point. At a later time the generated image (bitmap) from the snapshot will be delivered to the user.

I have the onMapReady function all set like so

```
override fun onMapReady(map: GoogleMap?) {

    map?.let {
        //add route
        it.addPolyline(routeLines)

        //add markers
        for(marker in markerOptions) {
            it.addMarker(marker)
        }


        val callback = GoogleMap.SnapshotReadyCallback(){
            saveSnapshot(it)
        }
        it.snapshot(callback)
    }
}
```

But before the onMapReady can even be called, the map itself needs to initiated.

```
var mMap: GoogleMap? = null
```

How do I create a map in memory only with no visual?

Thanks
^.^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a limitation of Google Maps. Reading the GoogleMaps class [documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.html), it couldn't be done like you can with MapKit in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Maps Static API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro)  or try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48631146/6950238) solution based on `MapView` [lite mode](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/lite):

> ```
> ...
> mMapView = new MapView(this, options);
> mMapView.onCreate(mapViewBundle);
>
> mMapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
>         @Override
>         public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
>
>             // form your card (add markers, path etc.) here: 
>             googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
>                     .position(KYIV)
>                     .title("Kyiv"));
>
>             // set map size in pixels and initiate image loading
>             mMapView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mMapWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
>                     View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mMapHeight, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
>             mMapView.layout(0, 0, mMapWidth, mMapHeight);
>
>             googleMap.setOnMapLoadedCallback(new GoogleMap.OnMapLoadedCallback() {
>                 @Override
>                 public void onMapLoaded() {
>                     mMapView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
>                     mMapView.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mMapWidth, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY),
>                             View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(mMapHeight, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY));
>                     mMapView.layout(0, 0, mMapWidth, mMapHeight);
>                     mMapView.buildDrawingCache(true);
>                     Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(mMapView.getDrawingCache());
>                     mMapView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(false);
>                     mImageView.setImageBitmap(b);
>
>                 }
>             });
>
>         }
> });
> ...
> ```