# How to show dynamically screenshot of lat long in list Android?

Tags: android, google-maps

I am stuck to show a list of lat, long as a real-time location like the screenshot, please help me, give me a solution?

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to display static google map on android imageview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5324004/how-to-display-static-google-map-on-android-imageview)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the google [maps static api](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro)